# Vue.js data can not be initialized with property values

Tags: vuejs2

It should be possible to directly reference property inside data value.
But for some reason in does not work. I created a small example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ay7fue0s/

As a workaround Im doing right now this:

```
computed: {
    foo() {
        this.whyDoesNotWork = this.message;
    }
},
watch: {
    foo() {}
}
```

So the computed function is mutating data directly. Very hacky and probably wrong.
Does anyone know whats wrong with the initial example of just referencing property?

Comment: don't use arrow function to return your data (the Vue component context is lost with it)  :   `data() {  return {     whyDoesNotWork: this.message  } }`

Comment: [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/gapvdao1/)

Comment: Would have never noticed it myself! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['message'],
  data() {
    return {
        whyDoesNotWork: this.message
    }   
  },
  template: '<span>{{ whyDoesNotWork }}</span>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hello: {},
    message: 'someting'
  },
  components:['child'],
  template: '<child :message="message"></child>'
})
```

> Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback because an arrow function wouldn't bind this to the vue instance for which you are defining the computed property.